# Mupdf highlight text to same area

Tags: android, highlight, mupdf

Multiple operating in the same area of text, text gradually blurred

This is a very obvious bugs.

How do I solve it ?

No.

Comment: Do I have a problem that no one can show it again ?             issue-Image -> bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=11169        Who can help me have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense to me. What do you mean by 'operating in the same area of text' ?

Perhaps if you shared a copy of the PDF file, and explained what you are doing, we could look at it.

Comment: When I select a part of the text to highlight, then I highlight the same place again.

The highlight text will be blurred.

I don't know I said this will make you understand.

Comment: What operating system is this for ? Are you using a standard MuPDF binary downloaded from Artifex, or did you build it yourself ? If you built it yourself, is this *your* application using MuPDF, or our demonstration code ? Can you post an example PDF file to a public URL please so we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: The highlight annotation uses transparency, if you repeatedly apply highlighting, then the text will get fainter, possibly this is what you mean ?

Comment: Yes! I mean what you say.

Sorry, I don't have so much media upload permissions.

I don't know how to upload the apk file.

Comment: Well, that doesn't look like a bug. Highlighting is applied using transparency, so if you apply it twice, the background will get fainter. If you don't want that, then don't do it. Its hard to see what you gain by highlighting twice. Oh, and I was *not* asking for the apk, but a PDF file which can be used to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Operation highlight will appear on any of the PDF file.

I also operating on other PDF reader app(adobe、foxit etc.) is no problem.

Comment: This problem can't repair.

I hope you to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have "solved" this by telling mupdf to write highlight annotations such that they are rendered using multiplicative color mixing. They will then appear to be "behind" the text, as black stays black when you multiply colors.

To do this, you can go into source/pdf/pdf-annot.c and in the function

```
pdf_annot *
pdf_create_annot(pdf_document *doc, pdf_page *page, fz_annot_type type)
```

after

```
if (annot_arr == NULL)
{
    annot_arr = pdf_new_array(doc, 0);
    pdf_dict_puts_drop(page->me, "Annots", annot_arr);
}
```

add something like

```
if (type == FZ_ANNOT_HIGHLIGHT) {
        //Say that we want this to be renderd "behind" the text, i.e., in multiplicative mode
    pdf_dict_puts_drop(annot_obj, "BM", pdf_new_name(doc, "Multiply"));
}
```

Hope that helps.